# How to display/order unit tests by date created in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, tdd, test-explorer, katana

I am new to a fairly large code base(in my case is the [Project Katana](http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/) source code).

I am studying the unit tests in the project in order to get acquainted with the code base (there are around 554 tests in the solution).

Since there are a considerable number of unit tests, I would like to study/review them in the order they were created.

**I cannot seem to find a way in Test Explorer to arrange the unit tests in chronological order**. A quick internet search found nothing.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: In the meantime, I will review the unit tests in an alternative order: by using the library and then looking through the test methods corresponding to the method I want to use. From the perspective of a consumer of the project, I believe this may be a more efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

An approach that just occurred to me (although not ideal) would be to open the first commit of the source code and go from there.

Although this does not answer the question of how to arrange them in the chronological order in Test Explorer, it does gives us the opportunity to look at the tests in chronological order. A brute force approach.